# Custom Component 3 levels deep

Tags: component, development, joomla-3.3.x

IM building a component and im trying to work out how to do this

Bookings / Orders / Order

I have a bookings view and form
I have a orders view and form

However...

Im having trouble getting bookings to show orders based on booking id. I have added to the models file WHERE bid=GET[bid]

However that messes things up when coming back from editing an order.

The steps are

- click bookings
- view orders based on booking id ( my custom hack in the models file for orders )
- open order
- edit order
- click save
- return to orders view where booking id=booking id

I can manage this by adding a little hack into the controllers order.php file

but...

That works for saving and going back and yet it crashes all other actions like publish,archive etc..

There must be a section in the mvc where i can put the additional &bid=$_GET['bid'] and it works across all submission actions.

What is the correct way to build a component with views that are parent to each other.

Im happy to provide code but theres quite a lot. So maybe if you could direct me first.

some other notes:

here is my link to the orders from the bookings view

```
JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_tourbookings&view=orders&bid='.(int) $row->id)
```

Here is my hack within the models/orders.php

```
$query->where('a.bid = '.$_GET['bid']);
```

So far that works good, if i click it ill get the orders based on bid.

Then i am lost. Because if i try to hack from here i am completely stuck as it wont come back to the orders based on bid without crashing.

If i hack the controllers/order.php ( which has changed again in joomla 3.3+ )

I find that it kind of works and allows me to go back to the previous page with bid=bid attached but if i try to archive,unpublish or do anything of that sort im stuck.

Cheers
John

Comment: First of all - never ever do like this `$query->where('a.bid = '.$_GET['bid']);` because you will be hacked. It is called [SQL Injection](http://docs.joomla.org/Securing_Joomla_extensions). Second - I do not understand why there is a problem when all other actions does not work. What exactly is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is very general. At first glance:

- The question depends on how you are implementing a MVC in Joomla! and which Controller flavour are you following. In my perspective, I avoid any MVC issue just relaying on [FoF](https://github.com/akeeba/fof), instead of elucidating how to implement a native controller in Joomla 2.5, 3, or 3.x.
- DO NOT use $_GET, for security reasons. Instead of using the raw variables, implement JInput. For example, FoF implements F0FInput, extending JInput.

Comment: Hi, yes youre right. Its definatley a steep learning curve. I have decided to take a more simplistic approach. IT would be so much better if i could undertsand how the relationships work between data. It seems that when bulding a component there is only - list view and edit or form view - what if you wanted list view based on dates / list view of all those dates / edit or form view of that item

Comment: Yes, this is the common Joomla MVC. If you want to add a new subview parameter you can do it. For instance, in FoF you have layout or type (e.g. json) parameters, they are used to load different "subviews" in the same view/tmpl directory.

Comment: Oh cool, im going to look now. I really want to understand this. If i can get my head around it would be really powerful for building more hardcore components.

Comment: i just looked at the FOF page. Over my head. Any way of pointing me to a page the has a tutorial on creating a sub-view and using the FoF - please.

Comment: Sure, please check this chapter: Chapter 2. Component overview and reference - https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/fof/fofview.html#id510150